# Can't connect to my mongodb localhost after using SSL/TLS certificates

Tags: mongodb, ssl, localhost, tls1.3

Each time I try connecting to my localhost server using SSL/TLS certificate I get an error which says, **connection attempt failed: HostUnreachable**

Things I've tried

- I've tried restarting my system
- I've tried changing the tls to SSL
- I've also cross-checked the file path for mongodb.pem,

I'm really at a loss.

This is the code I ran and the error I'm getting

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

This is my mongo.cfg file

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:


# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\log\mongod.log


# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

This is the command I used to connect to the server

```
mongo --tls --tlsCAFile mongodb.pem --host localhost
```

Comment: maybe add your mongod.conf file , is your mongod service running? Do you have localhost added to your net.bindIP setting? what command you use to connect? Also what is the error message in the mongod.log ? You may need to set preferSSL so you are able to connect also not encrypted ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
localhost was added to my net.bindIP setting, my mongod service was also running, I'll also update my question and add my mogod.conf file

Comment: I dont see in your config file where you add the certificates , maybe check the official docs here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/  and here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/

Comment: You enabled authorization. Do you want to authenticate with username/password or with X.509 certificate? In case of first, you miss username and password (and authentication database) in `mongo`. For the later case, you miss the certificate file.

Answer (score 0):

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
ssl:
mode: requireSSL
PEMKeyFile: /home/mongodb.pem
CAFile: /home/rootCA.pem

modify mongod.conf file